# Стоит ли заменять нулевой хендл (HANDLE, HWND, HMODULE, ...) на nullptr?

Tags: c++, winapi

Resharper постоянно советует заменить `NULL` на `nullptr` для хендлов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
HMODULE(HANDLE) определен  в winnt.h как некий указатель.
Однако, на самом деле, указателем он не является, а является просто идентификатором. Попытка обратиться к памяти, на которую он указывает, не приведет ни  к чему хорошему. Т.е. само по себе слово `nullptr` будет вводить в заблуждение.
Кроме того, в WinAPI существуют хендлы, не декларированные как указатели.
Так что же делать?

Comment: Он же не советует менять не-указатели на `nullptr`?

Comment: @zenden2k Когда имеешь дело с Windows, API которого - это C функции, а не C++ функции, то я бы использовал те типы и алиасы, которые определены в Windows и игнорировал бы данное сообщение среды разработки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `nullptr` везде, где ожидаются указатели и `0` в остальных местах. Не используйте `NULL` вообще нигде, R# правильно подсказывает.

---

А для того, чтобы намерения были более явными, то нужно немного потрудиться и добавить классы, типа этого:

```
class HModule
{
public:
    HModule() = default;
    HModule(HMODULE module):
        m_Instance(module)
    {}
    operator HMODULE()
    {
        return m_Instance;
    }
private:
    HMODULE m_Instance = nullptr;
};
```

Тогда использование будет явным:
`GetModuleFileName(HModule{}, ...)`
Приятным бонусом такого подхода является RAII, которое плавно вытекает из такого подхода. Остаётся лишь добавить деструктор, который будет использовать соответствующую функцию освобождения, если в этом есть нужда.

Comment: Чем ваше "RAII" отличается от простого "RAII" вида HMODULE hModule = SomeModule;? Какие ресурсы ваш класс захватывает и освобождает при удалении соответствующего объекта класса?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, очевидно, что нужно добавить что-то в деструктор.

Comment: Что именно добавить?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, то, что будет освобождать ранее полученный `HMODULE`.

Comment: А что будет освобождать ранее полученное HMODULE?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, понятия не имею. Это никакого отношения к вопросу не имеет, как и к ответу, собственно.

Comment: Как это не имеет отношения к ответу, когда простой тип HMODULE вы предлагаете использовать не напрямую, а через некоторый класс, который на самом деле ничего не делает, а лишь добавляет работу программисту?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, в моём ответе содержится *идея* класса, о чем там, собственно, и написано — «типа этого». Если хэндл нужно закрывать, то, разумеется, нужно добавить деструктор с вызовом соответствующей функции. И да, я бы использовал именно такой подход, даже если там нечего закрывать, т.к. использование такого кода с моей точки зрения куда яснее, чем использование повсеместных `0/NULL/nullptr`

Comment: Я не вижу смысл вашей идеи, так как ничего конкретного вы не демонстрируете. HMODULE - это не тот ресурс, который выделяется пользователем. По крайней мере для вызова функции GetModuleFileName нет никакого смысла городить это. С таким же успехом вы можете обернуть тип int и везде вместо int использовать свой класс..

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, да, `int` тоже можно обернуть, если он покрывает некоторую сущность, а не просто целое число. В вопросе речь идёт о хэндлах win32 API в целом, а не только о HMODULE. Ну и если Вы не видите смысла, что ж,— я вижу.

Comment: Вы сослались на RAII, а я нигде не вижу RAII в вашей конструкции, использующей HMODULE. Вот и прошу показать мне,, где здесь RAII.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, я дополнил пост, чтобы было понятнее, что я имею ввиду.

Comment: С моей точки зрения ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 1):

`HMODULE` - это самый настоящий указатель, он указывает на базу модуля (его начало в памяти), так что вполне логично использовать для него `nullptr`.

`HANDLE` - это некоторый дескриптор (описатель), который имеет тип "указатель на что-то".
В зависимости от того, какая функция выдала хендл, невалидное значение может меняться. Например для хендла файла `0` является валидным значением, а `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == (HANDLE)-1` - невалидным. Для процессов - `0` является не валидным значением, а `(HANDLE)-1` - валидным (текущий процесс).

Тем не менее, тип `HANDLE` - это указатель, а для указателей в С++ есть `nullptr`. `NULL` устарел, и не надо его больше использовать.